# Java Plugin for Chrome on OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.2

Tags: macos, java

I'm trying to use webex in Chrome.  To click on webex links, I need the java plugin.  However, it appears that a recent OS X Mountain Lion update removed the java plugin from my computer.

When I try to install the java plugin in chrome, I see the following error:

[image]

```
Chrome does not support Java 7. Java 7 runs only on 64-bit browsers and Chrome is a 32-bit browser.

If you download Java 7, you will not be able to run Java content in Chrome and will need to use a 64-bit browser (such as Safari or Firefox) to run Java content within a browser. Additionally, installing Java 7 will disable the ability to use Apple Java 6 on your system.
```

Fine, so I try to download the Java 6 plugin instead, but it appears that Oracle has no Java 6 plugin.

What gives?  How do I install the java plugin for Chrome?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are in luck, Apple released a "fix" for this issue:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559

Basically Apple has provided some terminal commands that move the plug-in from the disabled folder to where it needs to be to work in Chrome.

However you would be better off (read: SAFER!) by using the updated Java plugin [from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1637588.html) and a browser that can use that plugin, like Firefox or Safari.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me. Even after restarting Chrome, Chrome still didn't pick up the plugin (and didn't list it in about:plugins either). Is there something one needs to do to force Chrome to reload it's plugin list?

Comment: Correction: I got this to work. Strangely it looks like if I create the symlink in Step (3) in place, I don't have permission to resolve it (I get errors even in Terminal). I created the symlink in my home directory, then moved it to `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins`. That seemed to work. I don't quite understand why.

Answer (score 1):

The Chromium project is working on it according to issue [18323](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=18323), [115774](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=115774) and [175129](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=175129). So just give issue [18323](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=18323) and issue [115774](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=115774) a star to raise its importance for the Chromium developers.